# How would I say two triangles are congruent?

Tags: symbols

There is a sign to signify two triangles are congruent. It looks like this: ≅. How would I do this in latex?

Comment: `\usepackage{amssymb}` and then `\cong`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
 $\triangle A \cong \triangle B$
  \end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Use \usepackage{amssymb} package and \cong command.

I strongly refer you to consult with [List of LaTeX mathematical symbols](https://oeis.org/wiki/List_of_LaTeX_mathematical_symbols#Trigonometric_functions) link. It will help you a lot.

Comment: Why do you need to include `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`?

Comment: Oh that not necessary for your problem.